# Converting signed binary string in two's complement to int?

Tags: java

I have a binary string as follows:

```
String bin = "1101";
```

and I want my int's value to be `-3` instead of `13`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you assuming that *every* string with a leading 1 is negative? Would 13 have to be represented as "01101"? Or have you got a fixed size of 4 bits? More details required, basically.

Comment: `Long res = Long.parseLong(bin, 2); if (bin.charAt(0)=='1' && bin.length()==n) res -= (1L<<n);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `if (i >= k) i -= 2 * k;` Where `k` is the smallest positive number your scheme cannot represent. (8 in this case, because `0111` is 7 and `1000` would be negative.)

`13` is greater than `8`, so you'd subtract `16` from `13`, giving `-3`.