# Binary value in java 6

Tags: java, binary, type-conversion, java-6

I have this binary value :

```
11001001111001010010010010011010.
```

In java 7, if I declare:

```
int value = 0b11001001111001010010010010011010;
```

and print the value I get -907729766.

How can I achieve this in Java 6 as well?

Comment: Why are you using Java 6? It's obsolete.

Comment: This is the version our server runs on...can't really change that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there binary literals in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961091/are-there-binary-literals-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting signed binary string in two's complement to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512699/converting-signed-binary-string-in-twos-complement-to-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to parse it as a `long` first, then narrow it into `int`.

```
String s = "11001001111001010010010010011010";
int i = (int)Long.parseLong(s, 2); //2 = binary
System.out.println(i);
```

Prints:

```
-907729766
```

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know since Java 8 there is [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-) method which lets you parse your data without problems

```
String s = "11001001111001010010010010011010";
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s,2));
```

Output: `-907729766`

Java is open source so you should be able to find this methods code and adapt it to your needs in Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the value you entered, because it is outside of the limit of Integer. Use the radix 2 to convert it on Java 6.

This will fail

```
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("11001001111001010010010010011010", 2));
```

with 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11001001111001010010010010011010"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)

But this will work

```
 System.out.println(Long.parseLong("11001001111001010010010010011010", 2));
```

the output will be 3387237530

Comment: That is because the value int -907729766 is actually the long value 3387237530. Try this:         long l = 3387237530L;
        System.out.println((int)l);

Comment: @AlexandreSantos Not exactly. Decimal value of int `-907729766` is same as decimal value of long `-907729766L`. It binary representation of int `-907729766` is same as binary representation of long `3387237530L` (at least at last 32 bits).

Comment: Sure, but System.out.println((int)l) doesn't print the binary, it prints with the overflow.