# Convert 24 bits two's complement to signed decimal number in Java

Tags: java

i use the following way to convert 16 bits to signed decimal:

```
(short) Integer.parseInt("1110111100001010", 2))
```

the problem is that i have 24 bits to convert to signed decimal.

Comment: You can't use a `short` then. Either use a `int`, or be prepared to lose some of the bits. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: i cannot lose data, and i know that short and int are not appropriate method to convert 24 bit, i was just asking if anyone ever had a problem like this that already solved.

Comment: Use an `int` and not worry about the unused 8 bits?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to find the value of the trailing 16 bits? Like you want to ignore the first 8 bits when performing your two's complement interpretation?

Comment: i said i want to convert a binary string like "100111110000111101101010" to decimal signed number without any lost of data.

Comment: @Daniele_r81 If you're always casting to a short then that quite simply is not possible.

Comment: sorry maybe i didn't explain my problem, I'm not saying i m casting to short, i said I'm looking for a method to convert 24 bit to signed decimal, doesn't mater how but i can't lose data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BigInteger that has no size limit. Means you will not lose any data no matter how big your binary string gets.

And for making it signed I refer to a simple trick discussed here:
[Converting signed binary string in two's complement to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512699/converting-signed-binary-string-in-twos-complement-to-int)

So here are two methods: one for int and one for BigInt

```
public static String generateKString(String binary){
    // k is the smallest positive number the actual binary scheme cannot represent
    // for 1101 it is 1000
    String kStr = "1";
    for(int i = 1; i < binary.length(); i++)
        kStr += "0";
    return kStr;
}

public static BigInteger convertSignedBigInt(String binary){
    BigInteger bInt = new BigInteger(binary, 2);        
    String kStr = generateKString(binary);      
    BigInteger k = new BigInteger(kStr, 2);     
    if (bInt.compareTo(k) == 1) bInt = bInt.subtract(k.multiply(new BigInteger("2")));
    return bInt;
}

public static int convertSignedInt(String binary){
    int i = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
    String kStr = generateKString(binary);
    int k =  Integer.parseInt(kStr, 2);
    if (i >= k) i -= 2 * k;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: no, that not right cause in this way i don't have sign.